# Generate a report in commvault by time scheduled

Tags: commvault

How can someone generate a report in commvault that lists jobs by schedule timed?  For instance, if I have jobs scheduled at 8:00pm every night, is there a way to show all jobs that happen between 8 and 9 pm where it gives this time range and then shows all the jobs that are scheduled.

It would be nice if it could be generated to show all 24 hour intervals and hopefully in a calendar view.  I'm not sure if this is supported, however, manually documenting this information is going to be labor intensive.

Ideally the report would look like:

`Monday`

`8-9 pm   |   windowserver1,windowserver2`

`9-10 pm  |   linuxserver1,linuxserver2here`

`10-11 pm  |`

`11-12 pm  |  fsbackup1, fsbackup2`

Or if there are simliar reports, that might work, that would be great as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using 'Save as script' option for sample report and then checking if you can tweak xml file used by qcommand in that script.You may be able to change time values in that xml file. Unfortunately I don't have Commvault console handy to verify.